# Split a string of numbers passed to stored procedure and perform a lookup in a table

Tags: string, oracle, plsql, split

I have to pass string of numbers ( like 234567, 678956, 345678) to a stored procedure, the SP will split that string by comma delimiter and take each value ( eg: 234567) and do a look up in another table and get the corresponding value from another column and build a string.

For instance if have a table, `TableA` with 3 columns `Column1`, `Column2`, and `Column3` with data as follows:

```
1 123456 XYZ 
2 345678 ABC
```

I would pass a string of numbers to a stored procedure, for instance `'123456', '345678'`.  It would then split  this sting of numbers and take the first number - 123456 and do a look up in `TableA` and get the matching value from `Column3` - i.e. 'XYZ'.

I need to loop through the table with split string of numbers ('12345', '345678') and return the concatenated string - like "XYZ ABC"

I am trying to do it in Oracle 11g.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Can you provide more details, or some pseudo-code and/or existing table structures.

Comment: nice title.  what have you tried btw?

Comment: If you Google `oracle split function` you'll get plenty of hits where folks have implemented their own `split()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost always more efficient to do everything in a single statement if at all possible, i.e. don't use a function if you can avoid it.

There is a little trick you can use to solve this using [`REGEXP_SUBSTR()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions150.htm#SQLRF06303) to turn your string into something usable.

```
with the_string as ( 
  select '''123456'', ''345678''' as str
    from dual
         )
 , the_values as (
 select regexp_substr( regexp_replace(str, '[^[:digit:],]')
                     , '[^,]+', 1, level ) as val
   from the_string
connect by regexp_substr( regexp_replace(str, '[^[:digit:],]')
                        , '[^,]+', 1, level ) is not null
        )
 select the_values.val, t1.c
   from t1
   join the_values 
     on t1.b = the_values.val
```

This works be removing everything but the digits you require and something to split them on, the comma. You then split it on the comma and use a hierarchical query to turn this into a column, which you can then use to join.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d311/16) as a demonstration.

Please note that this is highly inefficient when used on large datasets. It would probably be better if you passed variables normally to your function...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  It did work, but as you suggested I would go with a function.

Comment: I suggested you to _not_ use a function @user2379643 :-); it'll be quicker if you don't. I suggested that you don't pass concatenated strings if you can avoid it

Comment: I have to pass string of numbers so, I don't have a choice, do I?

Comment: If you don't know the number of numbers you're passing then you may have no choice, I'd do everything possible to not do this though @user2379643. You _can_ simply put this query in a function though...